# Is it possible to use non-root element as reactive object in Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

The tutorial of Pinia shows the simplest case for a reactive property: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/
Defines a counter and increases. There is no need for getters and actions.

Is it possible to do the same with an element of the store which is not in the root (e.g.: `state: () => ({ count: {realCount: 0}, name: 'Eduardo' })` ) ?

So in a component:
`` `setup() { ``
    `const store = useStore();`
    `const {count, name} = storeToRefs(store)`
    `const realcount = MAGIC(count.realcount)`
`` }` ``

Is there any functionality? If not, then what is the suggested pattern? Getters + actions? Any shorter?
Should I flat everything in the object and write universal getter setter?

Answer (score 0):

`storeToRefs` helper is specific to Pinia because it takes store structure into account. As for store state, it's regular Vue reactive object and this isn't different than with any other:

```
const realcount = toRef(count, 'realcount');
```

Or:

```
const { realcount } = toRefs(count);
```

It would be impossible to make it work like `MAGIC(count.realcount)` because this would result in `count.realcount` value being passed to `MAGIC`, not `count` reference and not `realcount` property name.